# Mysqli query not returning any information?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im attempting to find the next date. For what ever reason, the below code is not returning any information. I have 1 entry formatted as such : 2017-03-18 12:37:00.... what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'db');
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
$query = "SELECT * FROM group WHERE date_time >= NOW() order by date_time LIMIT 1";
$next = mysqli_query($link, $query);
echo $next;
?>
```

Comment: This is not how you examine data returned from a database query.  You may want to start with some tutorials and examples of using `mysqli` in PHP.  You need to extract results from `$next`, likely in a loop.  You can't just print a complex object directly like that.

Comment: $next is an array you have to fetch. Echo will return nothing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call a fetch function to get the data from the query. You should also check if it found anything; the `fetch` function will return `null` instead of an array if no rows were matched by the query.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE date_time >= NOW() ORDER BY date_time LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row) {
    $date_time = $row['date_time'];
    echo "Next date is " . $date_time;
} else {
    echo "No time after now in the table.";
}
```

Comment: How do I echo that info? Ive tried `var_dump` `echo` `printf` Im not getting anything...

Comment: not sure why but I had to escape the terms in the query... wih ```

Comment: Because `GROUP` is a reserved word, since it's part of `GROUP BY`. It's best not to use reserved words as table and column names.

Answer (score 0):

With your code you return your query pointer. You're missing one line to fetch the entries.

https://secure.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Here is a good example how to achieve that.

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
```

Comment: I need further assistance. I tried to manipulate the above code 100 different ways and endup with nothing.

Comment: Since the query uses `LIMIT 1`, there's no need to fetch in a loop.